# CruiseControl / phpUnderControl Artifacts issues

Tags: phpunit, cruisecontrol, artifact, phpundercontrol

I have set up Git and CruiseControl, and just finished getting phpUnderControl working (a nightmare in itself as it is missing packages and all sorts).

So I have all the plugins in it like phpunit and php-documentor.

When I run 'ant' on my project it builds fine (just to check my build.xml is good)

When running the build from PHPUnderControl it hangs on the graph generation

```
[cc]Sep-08 01:10:22 ecutePublisher- executing command: /root/phpUnderControl/bin/phpuc.php graph logs/BIOSYNERGY artifacts/BIOSYNERGY
```

And it sits here for hours, in 'publishing' status on cruisecontrol, but clicking in to says build complete, and I see maybe 4 out of an expected 9 graphs if I am lucky.

If I run it manually, it takes about 2 seconds and gives me all 9 graphs (but the building it still stuck on 'publishing' until I stop cruisecontrol.

Also, the Coverage atrifacts seem to work, but no index.html file is generated, so the tab for coverage shows an error.

Documentation sometimes works, sometimes doesn't but no errors about it.

Code browser never seems to display any code?

Is there something missing that the Artifacts Publisher needs?

```
<artifactspublisher subdirectory="api" dest="artifacts/${project.name}" dir="projects/${project.name}/build/api"/>
          <artifactspublisher subdirectory="coverage" dest="artifacts/${project.name}" dir="projects/${project.name}/build/coverage"/>
          <execute command="phpcb --log projects/${project.name}/build/log --output projects/${project.name}/build/phpcb"/>
          <artifactspublisher dir="projects/${project.name}/build/phpcb" dest="artifacts/${project.name}" subdirectory="php-code-browser"/>
          <execute command="/root/phpUnderControl/bin/phpuc.php graph logs/${project.name} artifacts/${project.name}"/>
```

Thanks for any help!

CC is installed at: http://pixelhero.co.uk:8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not tied to phpUnderControl, I recommend switching to [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) as it is actively developed and has a working [project template](http://jenkins-php.org/) by the main author of PHPUnit.

Comment: Yeh, I did end up switching to Jenkins - I am just used to cruise control from back when it was developed. Just need to get the PHP stuff set up in Jekins now. Any way to Password Protect Jenkins without doing it at server level?

Comment: @RichardEdwards - No, we use our system accounts. Post a new question or try the mailing list.